# Dash use in "There are a lot of opportunities and institutions—all essential for the research."

Tags: em-dash

Is it okay to write an incomplete sentence("all essential for the research") after the dash in the example below?

> There are a lot of opportunities and institutions—all essential for the research.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested sentence

> There are a lot of opportunities and institutions—all essential for the research.

is fine and sounds perfectly natural. In a very formal context you might prefer to write it in full

> There are a lot of opportunities and institutions—all of which are essential for the research.